# 400 Bad Request The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port, while Deploying Django to AWS with Docker and Let's Encrypt

Tags: reactjs, django, nginx, docker-compose, http-status-code-400

I am following the "Django on Docker Series" series by testdrivenio(https://testdriven.io/blog/django-docker-https-aws/) for deploying a project into a new domain. I am using Django as backend but when I try to access the backend url via the port it showing via docker ps command i.e.,

> http://0.0.0.0:443/

I get the following error,

[image: 400 error]

This is the docker-compose file I am using

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./myprojectname
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.staging
    image: 789497322711.dkr.ecr.us-east-3.amazonaws.com/myprojectname-staging:web
    command: gunicorn myprojectname.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8005
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/myprojectname_staging/web/static
      - media_volume:/home/myprojectname_staging/web/media
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.staging
  frontendimage:
    container_name: frontendimage
    image: 789497322711.dkr.ecr.us-east-3.amazonaws.com/myprojectname-staging:frontendimage
    stdin_open: true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: frontend/Dockerfile.staging
    # volumes:
    #   - type: bind
    #     source: ./frontend
    #     target: /usr/src/frontend

    #   - '.:/usr/src/frontend'
    #   - '/usr/src/frontend/node_modules'
    ports:
      - '1337:30'
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    depends_on:
      - web
  nginx-proxy:
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    build: ./myprojectname/nginx
    image: 789497322711.dkr.ecr.us-east-3.amazonaws.com/myprojectname-staging:nginx-proxy
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 443:443
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/myprojectname_staging/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/myprojectname_staging/web/mediafiles
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    depends_on:
      - web
  nginx-proxy-letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    env_file:
      - .env.staging.proxy-companion
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
    depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy

volumes:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
  certs:
  html:
  vhost:
```

My Nginx directory

```
└── nginx
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── custom.conf
    └── vhost.d
        └── default
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM jwilder/nginx-proxy
COPY vhost.d/default /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default
COPY custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/custom.conf
```

custom.conf

```
client_max_body_size 10M;
```

default

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 default ssl;
}

location /static/ {
  alias /home/myprojectname_staging/web/static/;
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}

location /media/ {
  alias /home/myprojectname_staging/web/media/;
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

What should be my next course of action?

Comment: In my opinion simpler tutorial for Django+React+Docekr+Lets Encrypt https://saasitive.com/tutorial/docker-compose-django-react-nginx-let-s-encrypt/

Comment: https://github.com/saasitive/django-react-boilerplate/issues/8